# Wait queue and race condition

Tags: linux-kernel

I'm reading "Linux Kernel Development" by Robert Love and found the code below to wait for an event.

```c
DEFINE_WAIT(wait);

add_wait_queue(q, &wait); 
while (!condition) {
    // What happens if condition is changed and wake_up() is called here ?
    prepare_to_wait(&q, &wait, TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE); 
    if (signal_pending(current))
        /* handle signal */ 

    schedule();
}

finish_wait(&q, &wait);
```

My question is as in the code above. What happens if condition is changed and `wake_up()` is called after condition check but before `prepare_to_wait`?
My (probably wrong) interpretation here is that because `prepare_to_wait` makes the thread `TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE` and calls `schedule()` after the condition is changed, it sleeps forever (unless it gets signaled or another `wake_up` is called).

Comment: Yes, this code is raced, between `prepare_to_wait` and `schedule` it should be checking for condition. Also, `add_wait_queue` is superfluous when `prepare_to_wait` is used. Where did you find this code?

Comment: @Tsyvarev seems from page 59 [here](https://www.doc-developpement-durable.org/file/Projets-informatiques/cours-&-manuels-informatiques/Linux/Linux%20Kernel%20Development,%203rd%20Edition.pdf).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this code is actually **raced**, between `prepare_to_wait` and `schedule` calls it should be a check for the `condition` (and breaking if it is satisfied).

Funny enough, in the following description the book refers (at page 60) to the implementation of function `inotify_read()` in `fs/notify/inotify/inotify_user.c` file:

```
DEFINE_WAIT(wait);
...
while (1) {
  prepare_to_wait(&group->notification_waitq,
    &wait,
    TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE);

  if (<condition>) // very simplified form of checks
    break;
  if (signal_pending(current))
    break;

  schedule();
}
finish_wait(&group->notification_waitq, &wait);
...
```

which according to the author "follows the pattern":

> This function follows the pattern laid out in our example. The main difference is that
> it checks for the condition in the body of the `while()` loop, instead of in the `while()`
> statement itself. This is because checking the condition is complicated and requires grabbing locks. The loop is terminated via `break`.

However, that code exhibits **another pattern**, which checks the condition between `prepare_to_wait` and `schedule` call. And that code is actually **correct** (race-free).
Also that code doesn't use `add_wait_queue`, which is superfluous in presence of `prepare_to_wait`.

In another book of the same author, Linux Driver Development (3d revision), usage of wait queues seems to be more accurate. See e.g. chapter 6, Advanced Char Driver Operations.

Comment: I'm currently reading the same book and actually found the same thing - the code in example is really raced.  But, does those `if(condition)` checks really helps? I mean this check can be the last statement before the call to `shedule()`, but the condition can change in between ! which will result in the same thing - condition will occur before the process actually falls asleep deriving indefinite sleep state. Is this the case, or I misunderstood something? Can you clarify on this please?) thank you

Comment: The call to `prepare_to_wait()` adds the current thread into the waitqueue and changes its state to non-running one. And `schedule()` call actually puts a current thread, which has non-running state, into the sleep. But would `wake_up` is called (by another thread) in-between, it both removes a thread from the waitqueue and modify its state to runnable. In that case calling `schedule()` won't put the thread into the sleep.

Comment: ah, so calling `schedule()` without setting the state to `non-running` first basically does nothing ? thank you for your comment